# SOAP/REST Webservices XML case sensitivity

Tags: web-services, rest, soap

I just got a doubt whether the XMLs we are using for our SOAP/REST-based web services are case-sensitive or or not? How does it work exactly?

Tell me both for the default soap envelope as well as for payload XMLs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`SOAP` is a specific instance of an XML language.

As such, it adheres to all the rules of XML.

One of these rules is that `XML` is case-sensitive.

Therefore `SOAP` is case sensitive as well.

Same is true for `REST`

Answer (score 10):

XML is always case-sensitive; it's defined that way by the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-terminology) (see the definition for “match” where it says that no case folding is performed). SOAP uses XML for both envelope and payload, so those are *by definition* case-sensitive.

(Note that this is different from HTML, which is case-*insensitive* for element and attribute names. That's because HTML is built on top of SGML, itself a much-more-complex predecessor to XML.)