# Case sensitivity of CXF REST posted XML

Tags: java, xml, cxf

As an upshot (and I can expound by code examples if necessary), I have just realized that my `REST` API, written in Java, provided by `CXF` and served by `Tomcat 7` is case sensitive when it comes to posting `XML` content.

Is there any way to make the XML, which usually is a marshalled representation of the entity a service creates, can be case insensitive?

I can certainly post examples of the entity class, service, and their annotations if necessary but as bare minimum, if an instance variable in the entity is `private String firstName`, the XML tag must be `<firstName>...</firstName>` and not `<firstname>...</firstname>` but I would like to make the latter marshall-able.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267797/soap-rest-webservices-xml-case-sensitivity

Comment: I guess that means no as the answer ?

Comment: no, that comment just talks to whether XML should be case sensitive or not.  how are you unmarshalling your payload?

Comment: CXF (servlet?) does it automatically, in response to my annotations

Comment: basically, my service takes the entity class declaration as its argument.  but when you post marshalled XML of that object, it understands it and marshals it automatically.  i don't have to do anything

Comment: not an answer, but possible lead: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html. it might also be possible to do what you're asking using CXF Interceptors, which can allow you raw access to the XML to manipulate as needed. HTH.

Comment: You don't want to do this, even if you find that you can. The whole XML ecosystem is case-sensitive.

Comment: I actually would like to do it only with one service because I am using a python library to generate XML, which forces lowercase across the board.  but i wholeheartedly agree with that idea.  it's a hack.

Answer (score 1):

A complete solution involves a lot of work but it is perfectly possible. Following the link posted by @matiaselgart, the general solution would be

1 - Add a CXF Interceptor to manipulate the `Message`

2 - Read the incoming content, extract the XML, and process it with a `StreamReaderDelegate` to convert to lowercase

3 - Replace the content in Message with the output

The JAXB tags **should be in lowercase**, so the streamer could convert them easily, and be processed by JAXB unmarshaller. In your example `private String firstName`, the XML tag must be `<firstname>...</firstname>` and not `<firstName>...</firstName>`.

### CXF Interceptor

```
public class CaseInsensitiveInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public CaseInsensitiveInterceptor () {
        super(Phase.RECEIVE);
    }

    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
        //Get the message body as input stream, process the xml, and set a new non-consumed  inputStream into Message
        InputStream in = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
        InputStream bin = xmlToLowerCase (in);
        message.setContent(InputStream.class, bin);
    }

    public void handleFault(Message messageParam) {
        //Invoked when interceptor fails
    }
}
```

**Configuration**

Add the interceptor in the bus or in the provider

```
<bean id="caseInsensitiveInterceptor" class="CaseInsensitiveInterceptor " />
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <ref bean="caseInsensitiveInterceptor"/>
   </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:bus>
```

### Case Insensitive StreamReaderDelegate

I think you can use the `StreamReaderDelegate` from [here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/12/case-insensitive-unmarshalling.html) and convert the XMLStreamReader to InputStream using this [link](https://coderanch.com/t/478588/XMLStreamReader-InputStream) . The method `xmlToLowerCase` is called from interceptor

WARNING: I have not tested this part of the code.

```
private static class MyStreamReaderDelegate extends StreamReaderDelegate {

    public MyStreamReaderDelegate(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
        super(xsr);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeLocalName(int index) {
        return super.getAttributeLocalName(index).toLowerCase();
    }

    @Override
    public String getLocalName() {
        return super.getLocalName().toLowerCase();
    }

}

public InputStream xmlToLowerCase (InputStream in){
    XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
    XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(in);
    xsr = new MyStreamReaderDelegate(xsr);
    String xml = getOuterXml(xsr);
    return new ByteArrayInputStream (xml.getBytes());
}

//https://coderanch.com/t/478588/XMLStreamReader-InputStream
private String getOuterXml(XMLStreamReader xmlr) throws TransformerConfigurationException,
        TransformerFactoryConfigurationError, TransformerException
    {
        Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        transformer.transform(new StAXSource(xmlr), new StreamResult(stringWriter));
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
```